# What's difference between sun-java6-bin and sun-java6-jre .deb packages?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I just try understand what exactly difference between:
sun-java6-bin and sun-java6-jre .deb packages?

According to http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/flexiondotorg_java_/precise/main/base/sun-java6-bin here is no difference...

Thank you for ahead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [sun-java6-bin](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/flexiondotorg_java_/precise/main/base/sun-java6-bin) package contains architecture **dependent** files.  These are the binary files that needed to be compiled separately for the specific computer architectures supported by Ubuntu.

The [sun-java6-jre](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/flexiondotorg_java_/precise/main/base/sun-java6-jre) package contains architecture **independent** files.  These are files like images, icons, plain text files, or interpreted scripts that don't depend on any specific computer architecture.